Preset category checkbox from URL parameter when creating new post
I have added custom "New Post" links to the admin menus and dashboard widgets in the admin panel to allow administrators/editors to post new content with the category preset when the editor loads. The custom links are in the following format: <?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'post-new.php?preset_category=4' ) ); ?>.
The following function block is included in my theme's functions file, but is returning an error. The returned error is categories undefined.
function custom_enqueue_gutenberg_category_script() {
  // Check if we're on the post-new.php page and if the category ID is in the URL
  if (is_admin() && isset( $_GET[ 'preset_category' ]) && get_current_screen()->base === 'post' ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // Get the category ID from the URL parameter
      const categoryId = '<?php echo esc_js($_GET[ 'preset_category' ]); ?>';
      console.log(categoryId); // Correctly captures and logs category URL parameter
  
      // Gutenberg uses a global object wp.data
      const wpData = wp.data;

      // Wait until the editor has fully loaded
      wpData.subscribe(() => {
        const categories = wpData.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'categories' );
        // If no category is selected, set the default category
        if (categories.length === 0) {
          wpData.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost({ categories: [parseInt(categoryId)] }); // Error returned: Uncaught TypeError: categories is undefined
        }
      });
    });
    console.log( 'Custom admin script loaded!' );
    </script>
  <?php }
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'custom_enqueue_gutenberg_category_script' );


you can do that on php side with this hook :
// the 2nd "post" of the hook is the post type
add_action("save_post_post", function ($post_id, $post, $update) {
    
    if ($update) { // a post is updated
        return;
    }
    
    if (!isset($_GET["preset_category"])) {
        return;
    }
    
    
    $term = get_term($_GET["preset_category"]);
    
    if (isset($term)) {
        wp_add_object_terms(
              $post_id
            , $term->term_id
            , $term->taxonomy
        );
    }
    
    
}, 10, 3);

